# .FX files mostly don't load and those that do dont work properly

Tags: directx, shader, effects, direct3d, directx-9

Basically I made a .x file model class with animations and all and each model class has a pointer for an effect file class,so i make a bunch of different models and i make them all use a single effect like a glow for example, so around `DrawSubset()` in the render function of each model are `Begin()` and `End()` for the effect.The problem is 90% of my .fx files(I tried making in FX composer and Rendermonkey,I tried loading samples,even simple ones)they don't load and it says the effect is null and if something manages to load,it makes all the geometry grey or slices parts of it off.This is basically my code(oh and the d3d device pointer is properly set,don't worry,the problem is not there):

```
***FXfileEntity.h***

#pragma once

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

class CFXFileEntity{
private:
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 m_d3dDevice;

    LPD3DXBUFFER pBufferErrors;
    D3DXEFFECT_DESC pEffectDesc;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags;

    D3DXHANDLE ambient, attenuation, bbmax, bbmin, bbsize, bcenter, bssize, bsmin, bsmax, diffuse,
    elapsed, emissive, envNormal, height, joint, jointW, jointWI, jointWIT, jointWV,
    jointWVI, jointWVIT, jointWVP, jointWVPI, jointWVPIT, last, normal, opacity,
    position, proj, projI, projIT, random, refraction, renderCT, renderDST, renderTC,
    renderTD, specular, specularP, standarGlob, TextureMat, time, UnitsScale, view,
    viewI, viewIT, viewP, viewPI, viewPIT, world, worldI, worldIT, worldV, worldVI,
    worldVIT, worldVP, worldVPI, worldVPIT;

    D3DXVECTOR4 amb4, att4, diff, emis, join, nor2, opa4, posit, ref4, rtc, spec, specP4;
    D3DXVECTOR3 att3, bbMax, bbMin, bbSiz, bCen, nor1, opa3, ref3, specP3;
    D3DXVECTOR2 opa2, ref2, rtd, specP2;

    float bsSiz, bsMin, bsMax, elapTime, heigtMap1, lasTime, opa1, ran, ref1, specP1, tim, unit;

    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 envNorm, heightMapT, nor3, opa5, ref5, rct, rdst, stdG;

    D3DXMATRIX jWor, jWI, jWIT, jWV, jWVI, jWVIT, jWVP, jWVPI, jWVPIT, pro, proI, proIT, texM,
    vie, vieI, vieIT, vieP, viePI, viePIT, wor, worI, worIT, worV, worVI, worVIT, worVP, worVPI,
    worVPIT;

public:
    LPD3DXEFFECT anEffect;
    UINT cPasses;

    CFXFileEntity(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3dDevice);
    ~CFXFileEntity();
    HRESULT Load(LPCTSTR path);
    void Set();
};
```

and for the function bodies:

```
#include "FXfileEntity.h"
#include <iostream>

CFXFileEntity::CFXFileEntity(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3dDevice) : m_d3dDevice(d3dDevice)
{
    anEffect = NULL;
    pBufferErrors = NULL;
    dwShaderFlags = 0;
    cPasses = 0;
}

CFXFileEntity::~CFXFileEntity(void)
{
    anEffect = NULL;
    pBufferErrors = NULL;
    dwShaderFlags = 0;
    cPasses = 0;
}

HRESULT CFXFileEntity::Load(LPCTSTR path)
{
HRESULT hr;
hr=D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(m_d3dDevice,path,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,&anEffect,NULL);

if(!anEffect)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "fail", "f", MB_OK);
}

if(FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "hr  failed", "hrf", MB_OK);
}

ambient = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Ambient" );
attenuation = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Attenuation" );
bbmax = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingBoxMax" );
bbmin = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingBoxMin" );
bbsize = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingBoxSize" );
bcenter = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingCenter" );
bssize = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingSphereSize" );
bsmin = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingSphereMin" );
bsmax = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "BoundingSphereMax" );
diffuse = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Diffuse" );
elapsed = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ElapsedTime" );
emissive = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Emissive" );
envNormal = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "EnviromentNormal" );
height = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Height" );
joint = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Joint" );
jointW = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorld" );
jointWI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldInverse" );
jointWIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldInverseTranspose" );
jointWV = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldView" );
jointWVI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldViewInverse" );
jointWVIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWolrdViewInverseTranspose" );
jointWVP = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldViewProjection" );
jointWVPI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldViewProjectionInverse" );
jointWVPIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "JointWorldViewProjectionTranspose" );
last = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "LastTime" );
normal = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Normal" );
opacity = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Opacity" );
position = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Position" );
proj = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Projection" );
projI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ProjectionInverse" );
projIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ProjectionInverseTranspose" );
random = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Random" );
refraction = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Refraction" );
renderCT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "RenderColorTarget" );
renderDST = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "RenderDepthStencilTarget" );
renderTC = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "RenderTargetClipping" );
renderTD = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "RenderTargetDimension" );
specular = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Specular" );
specularP = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "SpecularPower" );
standarGlob = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "StandardGlobal" );
TextureMat = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "TextureMatrix" );
time = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "Time" );
UnitsScale = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "UnitsScale" );
view = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "View" );
viewI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ViewInverse" );
viewIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ViewInverseTranspose" );
viewP = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ViewProjection" );
viewPI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ViewProjectionInverse" );
viewPIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "ViewProjectionInverseTranspose" );
world = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "World" );
worldI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldInverse" );
worldIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldInverseTranspose" );
worldV = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldView" );
worldVI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldViewInverse" );
worldVIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldViewInverseTranspose" );
worldVP = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldViewProjection" );
worldVPI = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldViewProjectionInverse" );
worldVPIT = anEffect->GetParameterBySemantic( NULL, "WorldViewProjectionInverseTranspose" );

D3DXHANDLE hTech;
anEffect->FindNextValidTechnique( NULL, &hTech );
anEffect->SetTechnique( hTech );

return hr;
}

void CFXFileEntity::Set()
{
m_d3dDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &wor );
m_d3dDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &pro );
m_d3dDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &vie );
D3DXMatrixInverse( &proI, NULL, &pro );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &proIT, &proI );
D3DXMatrixInverse( &vieI, NULL, &vie );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &vieIT, &vieI );
vieP = vie * pro;
D3DXMatrixInverse( &viePI, NULL, &vieP );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &viePIT, &viePI );
D3DXMatrixInverse( &worI, NULL, &wor );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &worIT, &worI );
worV = wor * vie;
D3DXMatrixInverse( &worVI, NULL, &worV );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &worVIT, &worVI );
worVP= wor * vie * pro;
D3DXMatrixInverse( &worVPI, NULL, &worVP );
D3DXMatrixTranspose( &worVPIT, &worVPI );
tim = (float)GetTickCount()/1000.0f;

anEffect->SetFloat( time, tim );
anEffect->SetMatrix( proj, &pro );
anEffect->SetMatrix( projI, &proI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( projIT, &proIT );
anEffect->SetMatrix( view, &vie );
anEffect->SetMatrix( viewI, &vieI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( viewIT, &vieIT );
anEffect->SetMatrix( viewP, &vieP );
anEffect->SetMatrix( viewPI, &viePI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( viewPIT, &viePIT );
anEffect->SetMatrix( world, &wor );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldI, &worI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldIT, &worIT );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldV, &worV );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldVI, &worVI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldVIT, &worVIT );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldVP, &worVP );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldVPI, &worVPI );
anEffect->SetMatrix( worldVPIT, &worVPIT );
}
```

and in the model class it renders here:

```
this->Effect->Set();

    this->Effect->cPasses = 0;

    if( SUCCEEDED( Effect->anEffect->Begin(&this->Effect->cPasses, 0) ) ){

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < this->Effect->cPasses; i++)
     {
      Effect->anEffect->BeginPass(i);

      pDrawMesh->DrawSubset(iMaterial);

      Effect->anEffect->EndPass();
     }
      Effect->anEffect->End();
     }
```

I tried different values on cPasses depending on what I see in the .fx file,it doesn't really make a difference.Without the .fx files my .x files render perfectly with textures and animations...I never thought .fx files would be so hard,it's like the most confusing part of DirectX by far!

Comment: Can we see an FX File that doesn't work as well please?

Comment: @alwynd

Here is where I uploaded Game.rar with two examples,one is kur4i.fx that I made and the other is from the sample folder.

[Dox.BG](http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=f9a580a562)

the big green button translates Download Selected sorry I couldn't use another site,but for some reason the MultiUpload site didn't respond :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at "EdgeFuzz.fx" *please maybe post the file for everybody to see
The Shader uses the following for Vertex Input.

```
/* data from application vertex buffer */
  struct appdata {
     float3 Position    : POSITION;
     float4 UV      : TEXCOORD0;
     float4 Normal  : NORMAL;
     float4 Tangent : TANGENT0;
     float4 Binormal    : BINORMAL0;
};
```

I do not see a Vertex Buffer in your code, that matches the above semantics? i.e you will need to create a vertex buffer, matching the information vertex (semantic: POSITION), texturecoord: semantic: TEXCOORD0, normal (for lighting, semantic: NORMAL), (tangent and binormal for bump mapping)

The vertex buffer must then be filled with your mesh geometry in the structure as above (you will need to create a c++ struct to match the above hlsl struct)

Or is there more code you perhaps exlcluded from the post?
I hope this will be helpful to you, as that vertex shader will then take that geometry information, and do it's thing , when you invoke the technique (Main) (defined in the "EdgeFuzz.fx" shader)